# Prevent 2 Consecutive numbers regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate text input in JavaScript to prevent 2 consecutive numbers.
ex:

> name2aaa accept
>
> name22aa not accept

I am using the validation on text input. And that's my code, it's already contains prevent @ sign, I want to add the prevent 2 consecutive numbers rule to the same regex

```
 $('#storename').on('input', function () {
    var c = this.selectionStart,
        r = /[\\\@@]/g,
        v = $(this).val();
    if (r.test(v)) {
        $(this).val(v.replace(r, ''));
        c--;
    }
    this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
});
```

Comment: Use `/\d{2}/` and return failure if it matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

#### regex

```
[\\@]|(\d)\d+
```

- `[\\@]`: `\` or `@`
- `|`: or
- `(\d)\d+`: a digit with 1 or more digits ahead, put the first digit in group 1

#### substitution

```
$1
```

Assuming you don't want user to type another digit if there's already a digit before it.

When user tries to type `42`, it stores `4` in the group, and replace all the digits with that group. In this case, `42` -> `4`. So users can no longer type more than 1 digit in a row.

```js
$('#storename').on('input', function () {
    var c = this.selectionStart,
        r = /[\\@]|(\d)\d+/g,
        v = $(this).val();
    if (r.test(v)) {
        $(this).val(v.replace(r, '$1'));
        c--;
    }
    this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="storename" />
```

Comment: Thank you. it's working fine. please another question if I want to keep this rule but with just 4 numbers not 2 what is the change set that I need?

Comment: @rawanmansour That would be `[\\@]|(\d{3})\d+`